# Saving prediction_generator results in tensorflow and python

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0, prediction

Let's assume, we fitted a model in TensorFlow flow

```
model.fit(
    train_generator,
    epochs=epochs,
    verbose=1,
    steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
    validation_data=valid_generator,
    validation_steps=val_steps_per_epoch).history
```

In the next step, we generate predictions.

```
 Y_pred = model.predict_generator(valid_generator, np.ceil(valid_generator.samples / valid_generator.batch_size))
```

I'm wondering if it is possible to save predictions and load them from disk for debugging subsequent code without retraining the model and predicting the data each time after each restart.

Of course, it is possible to save and load the model, but there is still some overhead on predicting.

Any ideas are highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: why are you wondering instead of just save the prediction as you mentioned?

Comment: saving model != saving predictions

Comment: What I am wondering is, why you felt confused to save the model prediction into a disk, for example, the model predicts some handwritten digit and we save the predicted labels in a file. You can do an analysis with the predicted samples and ground truth later. So, what's the issue you're facing about it?

Comment: I want to save the exact copy of Y_pred to disk and to load it in the same format / data type as it was previously. And am wondering how do it the proper way. I feel like just dumping it is not the right way to go, but I also did not found a build-in solution

Comment: I see. Can you add some example code, where you tried to do something about it? It would be more clear. FYI, `predict_generator` is deprecated, use `predict` instead.

Comment: What more code do you need, any additional code means overload to the question. The question is simple. How to save and load Y_pred?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my understanding from the comment box, here is some possible solution for your query, let me know if it works for you or not.

> I'm wondering if it is possible to save predictions and load them from
> disk for debugging subsequent code without retraining the model and
> predicting the data each time after each restart.

---

First, we build a model and train it first.

```
import tensorflow as tf 

# Model 
input = tf.keras.Input(shape=(28, 28))
base_maps = tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28))(input)
base_maps = tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu')(base_maps)
base_maps = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=10, activation='softmax', name='primary')(base_maps) 
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[input], outputs=[base_maps])

# compile 
model.compile(
    loss = tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(),
    metrics = ['accuracy'],
    optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-3) )

# data 
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
x_train = tf.divide(x_train, 255)
y_train = tf.one_hot(y_train , depth=10) 

# customized fit 
model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=512, epochs=3, verbose = 1)
```

Next, We use this trained model to predict unseen data (`x_test`) and save the prediction to disk so that we can later debug model performance issue.

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 

y_pred = model.predict(x_test)       # get prediction 
y_pred = np.argmax(y_pred, axis=-1)  # get class labels

# save ground truth and prediction to local disk as CSV file
oof = pd.DataFrame(dict(
           gt = y_test, 
           pd   = y_pred, 
     ))
oof.to_csv('oof.csv', index=False)
oof.head(20)

# compute how many prediction are accurate or match 
oof['check'] = np.where((oof['gt'] == oof['pd']), 'Match', 'No Match')
oof.check.value_counts()
Match       9492
No Match     508
Name: check, dtype: int64
```

Like this, we can do various types of analysis from the model prediction and ground truth. However, in order to save probabilities (instead of actual labels), we can also do something like this: [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62150997/9215780).

```
y_pred = model.predict(x_test)
np.savetxt("y_pred.csv", y_pred , delimiter=",")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but what you save to disk are only the predicted labels (axix=-1). What about the rest? I would like to save the whole model.predict(x_text) object. You also do not load it back to ram.

Comment: Yes, here I saved the predicted labels. That's normally we do when you want to analyze model prediction - out-of-fold analysis.  But if you want to save predicted probabilities, you do that too, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62150997/9215780).

Comment: As you're wondering about re-loading, this is just a CSV file when we are saving them, so you can simply re-load it with `pandas.read_csv`.

Comment: yes, this is what I was looking for. If you rewrite your answer, I will accept it

Comment: I added this information. But please note that I didn't check with it for various causes, like regression or classification problems. So, I can't say if this is the best practice.

Comment: Is there is any query further? If it solves your query, please accept the answer to close the issue.